# I want to align items in inline-flex or inline-block and also be in the center

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, tailwind-css

[image]

I want to set the left and right margin with same amount.
I want to list my nft cards in format of below image, but they are not centered.
I just want to show them in grid style.

```
<div className="a-nfts">
            <div className="a-nft-card">A</div>
            <div className="a-nft-card">A</div>
            <div className="a-nft-card">A</div>
            <div className="a-nft-card">A</div>
            <div className="a-nft-card">A</div>
            <div className="a-nft-card">A</div>
            <div className="a-nft-card">A</div>
            <div className="a-nft-card">A</div>
</div>
//css
.a-nft-card{  
  display: inline-block;
  height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #000309;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: white 1px solid;
}
.a-nfts{  
  
  width: 60%; 
  border: 1px solid white;
  margin: auto; 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you wrap them in a flex container and set that to flex-wrap:wrap and justify-content: center then that will center the cards. Is that what you're looking for? I've made the container colour blue so you can see the effect.

```css
.container {
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.a-nft-card {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #000309;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: white 1px solid;
  color:white;
}

.a-nfts {
  width: 60%;
  border: 1px solid white;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="a-nfts">
  <div class='container'>
    <div class="a-nft-card">A</div>
    <div class="a-nft-card">A</div>
    <div class="a-nft-card">A</div>
    <div class="a-nft-card">A</div>
    <div class="a-nft-card">A</div>
    <div class="a-nft-card">A</div>
    <div class="a-nft-card">A</div>
    <div class="a-nft-card">A</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But if we use justify-content center, rest 2 cards will not be shown in the right format